# Oracle: Why dateStr and dateFmt using different date format can work well in Oracle TO_DATE( dateStr, dateFmt)?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, to-date

Oracle version:
`Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

Test:

```
select TO_DATE('2022.02.21','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;         --- convert success  
select TO_DATE('20220221','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;          --- convert success  
select TO_DATE('2022/02/21','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;        --- convert success
```

Why **dateStr** and **dateFmt** using different date format can work well in Oracle `TO_DATE( dateStr, dateFmt)`?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle will [ignore punctuation characters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5):

> #### String-to-Date Conversion Rules
>
> The following additional formatting rules apply when converting string values to date values (unless you have used the `FX` or `FXFM` modifiers in the format model to control exact format checking):
>
> - You can omit punctuation included in the format string from the date string if all the digits of the numerical format elements, including leading zeros, are specified. For example, specify `02` and not `2` for two-digit format elements such as `MM`, `DD`, and `YY`.
> - You can omit time fields found at the end of a format string from the date string.
> - You can use any non-alphanumeric character in the date string to match the punctuation symbol in the format string.
> - If a match fails between a `datetime` format element and the corresponding characters in the date string, then Oracle attempts alternative format elements, as shown in Table 2-20.
>
> Table 2-20 Oracle Format Matching
>
> | Original Format Element | Additional Format Elements to Try in Place of the Original |
> | --- | --- |
> | `'MM'` | `'MON' and 'MONTH'` |
> | `'MON'` | `'MONTH'` |
> | `'MONTH'` | `'MON'` |
> | `'YY'` | `'YYYY'` |
> | `'RR'` | `'RRRR'` |

Unless you use the [`FX` format modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA):

> `FX`
>
> Format exact. This modifier specifies exact matching for the character argument and `datetime` format model of a `TO_DATE` function:
>
> - Punctuation and quoted text in the character argument must exactly match (except for case) the corresponding parts of the format model.
> - The character argument cannot have extra blanks. Without `FX`, Oracle ignores extra blanks.
> - Numeric data in the character argument must have the same number of digits as the corresponding element in the format model. Without `FX`, numbers in the character argument can omit leading zeros.
> - When `FX` is enabled, you can disable this check for leading zeros by using the `FM` modifier as well.
>
> If any portion of the character argument violates any of these conditions, then Oracle returns an error message.

For example, given the queries:

```sql
select TO_DATE('2022.02.21','fxYYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
select TO_DATE('20220221','fxYYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
select TO_DATE('2022/02/21','fxYYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
select TO_DATE('2022-02-21','fxYYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
```

Then only the last one will work and the first 3 will raise the exception:

> ```
> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fe0b7cf7dd42d4c2b5191a9559d6a98c)*